# deleting inside a commit MongoDB scala

Tags: mongodb, scala

We are using Scala 2.10 and Mongo 2.4

I need to delete documents in collection A and B. 
Normally i would 
1. start a transaction
2. delete docs in A
3. delete docs in B
4. commit/Rollback

Is this supported in Mongo through the Scala driver(the wrapper for the Java driver). Can you please provide sample code

Answer (score 0):

MongoDb does not support transactions it supports only Atomic commit of single documents

see the [mongo docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-operations-atomicity/)

Comment: is two-phase-commit the right way to go about this??(http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/)

Comment: In theory yes,I have never tried it, note that they do say it can still be inconsistent as the process is still committing one record at a time ,any failures will need to be corrected by you not the DB.

Comment: I am ok with inconsistancy